# how to call the index of randomly sampled rows?

Tags: r

Let's say I randomly sample 3 rows from a data frame containing 10 rows:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(letters, 10), col2 = sample(letters, 10))

> df
    col1 col2
1     q    f
2     i    c
3     y    l
4     k    y
5     s    e
6     w    k
7     o    x
8     e    t
9     d    a
10    c    g

df_samp <- sample_n(df, 3)
## (sample_n is a dplyr function)

> df_samp
    col1 col2
6    w    k
2    i    c
1    q    f
```

How do I then find or call the index of the rows which were just sampled? (in this case rows 6, 2, and 1). For example, I'd like to delete or modify those three rows from the original data frame **df**. I tried to match the actual data

```
df <- df[-which(df$col1 == df_samp$col1 & df$col2 == df_samp$col2), ]
```

, which is not only inelegant but doesn't even work (error: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length").

Comment: Take a look at the row names of `df_samp`.  You can return them using `rownames(df_samp)`.  You can delete those rows from the original `df` using `df[-as.numeric(rownames(df_samp)), ]`

Comment: Or you could sample the row index directly `pick<-sample(nrow(df),3)`. Then get the selection `df[pick,]` or omit the selection `df[-pick,]` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Given a sample draw:

```
> df_samp
  col1 col2
7    t    j
8    a    w
3    k    y
```

You could subset by selecting all row names, except those in your random sample:

```
> df[ -as.numeric(rownames(df_samp)), ]
   col1 col2
1     g    p
2     u    g
4     d    c
5     f    k
6     r    m
9     n    h
10    o    x
```